# RStudio crashing with RcppGSL function

Tags: r, rcpp

I am working on speeding up one of my R programs, that solves a vector of score equations, with `Rcpp`. Since intermediate steps in computing these score equations require interpolation and numerical integration, I used `RcppGSL`. I have gotten it to the point where I can evaluate the score equations correctly for a given set of parameter values, but when I try to solve the equations in R with `multiroot` or `nleqslv`, RStudio crashes just before the parameter estimates are about to jump. It seems like there's a memory leak of some kind, and I bet it has something to do with the `GSL` routines (i.e. the allocation required for interpolation). Is there something that seems wrong in the "interpolation sections" below? I'm pretty new to `Rcpp` and `C++` overall, so I would be thankful for help with troubleshooting this!

I made a minimal example below - the actual function I am using has more score equations and has multiple interpolation/integration steps.

```
#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_interp.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multiroots.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>

// score equation u1
double u1Ex(Rcpp::NumericVector xVals, double a, double b, int nObs)
{
    std::vector<double> scoreVals(nObs);
    double scoreValSum, val;
    int ind;
    for(ind = 0; ind < nObs; ind++)
        {
            scoreVals[ind] = xVals[ind];
        }
    scoreValSum =  std::accumulate(scoreVals.begin(), scoreVals.end(), 0.0);
    val = scoreValSum*a + pow(b,2)/2 - 5;
    return val;
}



// score equation u2
double u2Ex(Rcpp::NumericVector xvals, double a, double b, int nObs)
{
    std::vector<double> scoreVals(nObs);
    double scoreValSum, val;
    int ind;
    for(ind = 0; ind < nObs; ind++)
        {
            scoreVals[ind] = -log(xvals[ind]);
        }
    scoreValSum =  std::accumulate(scoreVals.begin(), scoreVals.end(), 0.0);
    val = scoreValSum*a + b;
    return val;
}


// function that returns values of these score equations
// [[Rcpp::export]] 
Rcpp::NumericVector spModelExample(Rcpp::NumericVector params, Rcpp::NumericVector xInterp, Rcpp::NumericVector yInterp, const Rcpp::NumericVector xVals, int nObs)
{
    double a(1), b(1);
    int i, j;
    
    // INTERPOLATION SECTION
    
    // set up vectors for interpolation
    Rcpp::NumericVector yInterpTrue(11), Lambda01(11);
    
    // compute function that involves parameter
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        yInterpTrue[i] = params[1]*yInterp[i];  
    }
    
    // interpolation initiation
    gsl_interp_accel *acc01 = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
    gsl_interp *interpLambda01 = gsl_interp_alloc(gsl_interp_linear, xInterp.size());
    gsl_interp_init(interpLambda01, xInterp.begin(), yInterpTrue.begin(), xInterp.size());
    
    double result01;
    for(j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            // integration
            gsl_interp_eval_integ_e(interpLambda01,xInterp.begin(),yInterpTrue.begin(),0,xInterp[j],acc01, &result01);
            Lambda01[j]=result01;
        }

    gsl_interp_free(interpLambda01);
    gsl_interp_accel_free(acc01); 
    
    // END INTERPOLATION SECTION
     
    // initialize all parameters
    a = params[0];
    b = params[1];

    
    double u1Out = u1Ex(xVals, a, b, nObs);
    Rprintf("u1, = %f \n", u1Out);         
    
    double u2Out = u2Ex(xVals, a, b, nObs);
    Rprintf("u2 = %f \n", u2Out);

    
    // final score vector
    Rcpp::NumericVector scoreVec(2);
    scoreVec[0] = u1Out;
    scoreVec[1] = u2Out;
    
    return scoreVec;

}
```

When I run the following R code, I do successfully get a solution, but if I run it 5-10 times, RStudio will crash. I suspect that this has a similar cause to the issue I have with the more complex function (Note that `IDSplineScore` is the name of the package that contains my `Rcpp` function).

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppGSL)
library(IDSplineScore)
library(rootSolve)

set.seed(500)
xi.vals <- runif(100,0,10)
startval <- c(1.1,1.1)
x.interp <- seq(0,50,5)
y.interp <- 120-2*x.interp+rnorm(11,0,5)

multiroot(f = spModelExample, start = startval, verbose=TRUE, 
          xVals = xi.vals,
          xInterp = as.double(x.interp),
          yInterp = as.double(y.interp),
          nObs = as.integer(length(xi.vals)))
```

In case it's helpful, the sessionInfo() is below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] rootSolve_1.7       IDSplineScore_0.0.3 RcppGSL_0.3.3      
[4] Rcpp_0.12.15       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest using valgrind to debug this. See for example http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/05/debugging-with-valgrind/

Comment: BTW, I added `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]` to `gsl.cpp` and replaced `library(IDSplineScore)` with `sourceCpp("gsl.cpp")`. After that I was able to run your example more than 100 times without a crash. I am using R 3.4.4 on Linux.

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks for looking into this. After restarting my computer and not running the more complex version anymore, I also no longer found errors in this code. valgrind also looks clean for the code above, but I get a bunch of errors when I look at the real code (and once an infinite string of "Signal 11 being dropped from thread 0's queue"!!) Time to keep hunting, I suppose. Thanks again!